# Which word is more harsh to use: "geh raus" or "Hau ab"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, speaking

I assume the words "**Hau ab**" and "**geh raus**" have kind of same meaning. Which one is considered more harsh or strict way to say someone to get out?

Comment: One version I especially like is "Troll dich" which in a way seems nice but is actually quite harsh...

Answer (score 5):

**Geh raus!** comes from *rausgehen* which in turn comes from *herausgehen*. In the specified form this is just the imperative, which is not really rude in the literal sense (i.e. offensive). However, it is definitely impolite. It can be turned more polite by adding bitte, i.e. "Gehen Sie bitte (raus)". With the raus, this means the other person has to leave out of some kind of room, building, car, ... .

**Hau ab!** comes from *abhauen* which is colloquial and when used in the imperative mood less respectfull / more informal than *geh raus!*, which in my opinion would qualify as *more harsh*. This is also more universal, as this does not imply getting out of something (no *raus*). You can also say this to an animal that is bothering you (although chances you are successful are slim).

A more polite version would be:

> Würden Sie bitte gehen? *Would you please leave*

A rude version (offensive) would be:

> Verpiss dich gefälligst! *Fuck off already*

At the risk of pointing out the obvious: Unless another person is bothering you, it is generally considered impolite to ask someone to leave. You might want hint at it first or use some humor:

> Ich glaub ich muss Dich jetzt mal rausschmeißen, es wird langsam spät und ich muss morgen früh raus. (colloquial) *I think I need to kick you out now, it's getting late and I have to get up early*

If the person then does not leave, you can try the less polite versions.

Comment: A better alternative for "geh raus" would be "geh weg", which doesn't imply leaving a room.

Comment: Also nice (well, not nice, but idomatic): *Mach die Fliege!*, *Schwirr ab!*, *Verdufte!*, *Verdünnisier' dich*!"

Comment: *Die Bullen! Hau ab!* – *The cops! Scram!*

Comment: "geh raus" is *usually* impolite, but there are exceptions. A parent concerned that the kid is spending to much time indoors could say it with the meaning "get out to the open, get some fresh air/sunshine". And in summer 1990, before the final of the football (soccer) world cup, German coach Franz Beckenbauer ended his motivational speech to his players with "und jetzt geht raus und spielt Fußball" - and now get out and play football. And they did :-)

Answer (score 3):

Geh raus is a friendly way to say you should leave. Hau ab(!) is very harsh and unfriendly.

Answer (score 1):

*Geh raus* is no real substitute for *Hau ab*, because there are so many different reasons for going outside, e.g. for smoking.... Note that *Sollen wir rausgehen?* is a somewhat common invitation for a brawl.

*Verschwinde* would be a better alternative and while while pretty harsh could also be combined with polite *Sie * addressing.